# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x1a0b69400) to name.controller in specific scheme/target

Tags: ios, xcode7, packaging

I have a QA environment that runs fine, but When I switch schemes to production which uses a different target, one specific scene returns with this error. Its the scene where I recently added a new tableview controller. It makes no sense to me, seems like an Xcode bug. Are there any known workarounds or places to look? I tried removing the file from compile sources and adding it again but with no luck. I also tried cleaning project and removing derived data.

```
if (segue.identifier == "replies") {
    let dvc : repliesTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! repliesTableViewController
    dvc.currentMessage = self.currentMessage
   }
```

Comment: If possible, please show is some example of the code where you recieve this error. Possibly in some `segue` method you are trying an forced cast that fails, usually on the form e.g. `let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController`.

Comment: I updated answer with code. I don't believe the issue is with the code since it works fine with a different scheme.

Comment: what's the value of segue.destinationViewController ? in each case

Comment: the value is the same for both. 

class repliesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

Comment: do you have multiple schemes for a single target ? or have one scheme for each target ?

Comment: 1 scheme for each target

Comment: Its almost as if the repliestableview controller is being omitted from the build altogether. I also just tried renaming the class to see if it would make a difference but it did not

Comment: just to double-check, when you run app in both cases the value of segue.destinationViewController  is of type repliesTableViewController ?

Comment: Yes, in both cases it should be the exact same. I tried creating another source file and made sure all targets were selected when creating it. I still get the same result.

Comment: btw, in Swift class name should start with upper-case letter not with lower-case one

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was somehow the module in the Storyboard under custom class got switched to the specific QA as opposed to "current".